# ViewDeck issue with instances of viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, viewdeck

So on my center viewcontroller of my app I have a mapview.  I click a button and it toggled my left viewcontroller and displays my left view controller.  While I have my left viewcontroller open, I click a button and it closes the left viewcontroller and calls a method inside of the center view controller.  It does actually call the method, but I think it is on another instance of the center view controller, because it does show NSLog, but it actually doesn't update information on the center view controller.

So basically, my issue is that I 'think' its creating multiple instances of the center controller.  How an I access the FIRST instance to update data on it?

EDIT:  Okay so heres some code.

```
FirstViewController *controller = (FirstViewController*)[self presentedViewController];
[controller doSnap];
```

I've tried several variations of this.  Inside the method 'doSnap' I have an NSLog, and I have it do some things on the mapView.  The stuff ends up getting logged, but it does not actually display on the map, and I think the reason of this is because it is a different instance of the view controller.

Answer (score 2):

When using modal segues, you can just use the `presentingViewController` property to access the viewController that you came from.

```
YourOriginalViewController *controller = (YourOriginalViewController*)[self presentingViewController];
controller.yourPropertyToSet = whateverValue;
```

Comment: This did not work.  I still think there are multiple instances of my first view controller.